# How to change the class="" attributes of the crud table

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am trying to change the class attribute that Backpack 4.1 isusing for the  element in a list operation.
Currently I end up with something like this:

```
<table id="crudTable" class="bg-white table table-striped table-hover nowrap rounded shadow-xs border-xs dataTable dtr-inline collapsed has-hidden-columns" cellspacing="0" aria-describedby="crudTable_info" role="grid">
```

I would actually need to insert 'table-dark' and remove 'bg-white' from it to combine it with our design. How would this work?
I could change the container div but that won't do in this case it seems :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only option is to [create the same view file in your project](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-how-to#publish-a-column-field-filter-button-and-modify-it), in which Backpack will pick up *your* view instead of the *package* view. Of course, this means you'd forfeit all updates to that file, since Backpack will be using yours.

So you can do that using `php artisan backpack:publish crud/list`. This will copy the package file to your `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/list.blade.php` where you can make any changes you want to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a custom blade template (as @tabacitu mentions, this will lock you out of updates), another option is to add a script via a widget that listens for the [DataTables init event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/):

In your crud controller:

```
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\Widget;

protected function setupListOperation()
{
    Widget::add()->type('script')->content('path/to/script.js');
}
```

And the script:

```
$('#crudTable').on('init.dt', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('bg-white');
    $(this).addClass('table-dark');
});
```